# webkitdirectory in typescript and react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

The exact error is

```
Type '{ webkitdirectory: string; type: "file"; }' is not assignable to type 'DetailedHTMLProps<InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, HTMLInputElement>'.
  Property 'webkitdirectory' does not exist on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, HTMLInputElement>'.ts(2322)
```

or

```
Type '{ webkitdirectory: true; multiple: true; type: "file"; }' is not assignable to type 'DetailedHTMLProps<InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, HTMLInputElement>'.
  Property 'webkitdirectory' does not exist on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, HTMLInputElement>'.ts(2322)
(JSX attribute) webkitdirectory: true
```

The components just have a simple input with `webkitdirectory`, I've also tried `webkitdirectory=''`

```
import React from "react";

function FolderUpload() {
  return (
    <div className="FolderUpload">
      <input  webkitdirectory="" type="file" /> // webkitdirectory has the error
    </div>
  );
}

export default FolderUpload;
```

I understand its non-standard but its covered in the major desktop browsers which is enough for this project
https://caniuse.com/input-file-directory
and the moz doc https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/webkitdirectory

Answer (score 2):

Just adding one small thing to @kob003's answer, which I needed additionally apart from the answers provided here,

First I did this:

```
declare module "react" {
    interface InputHTMLAttributes<T> extends HTMLAttributes<T> {
        webkitdirectory?: string;
    }
}
```

But it was still throwing error  , then I changed

```
      <input  webkitdirectory type="file" />
```

to

```
      <input  webkitdirectory="" type="file" />
```

to be fully error free.

Answer (score 1):

If you using both typescript and ESLint, try this solution!

```js
const inputFolder = useRef<HTMLInputElement | null>(null);

return (
  <input 
    type="file"
    ref={(node) => {
      inputFolder.current = node;

      if (node) {
        ['webkitdirectory', 'directory', 'mozdirectory'].forEach((attr) => {
          node.setAttribute(attr, '');
        });
      }
    }}
  />
)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can declare it :

```
declare module "react" {
    interface InputHTMLAttributes<T> extends HTMLAttributes<T> {
        webkitdirectory?: string;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will find the as an [Issue in the React repo](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3468)

It will likely be fully solved in the future but for the moment you can use:

```js
<input directory="" webkitdirectory="" type="file" />
```

And if you run Typescript add this

```js
{/* @ts-expect-error */}
<input directory="" webkitdirectory="" type="file" />
```

to upload a directory

Answer (score 0):

Hacky as hell but this works too:

<input type="file" {...{ webkitdirectory: '', mozdirectory: '', directory: '' }} />